# Hiding NSSlider's tick marks

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder, appkit, nsslider

Is there a way to hide the tick marks of `NSSlider`?

Comment: Do you want to do this in Interface Builder or through code?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. It doesn't matter.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to keep the tickmark stopping behaviour but hide them, you can override the `NSSliderCell's` `-(NSRect)rectOfTickMarkAtIndex:(NSInteger)index`
and provide a rectangle with 0 dimensions.

Comment: up for this most correct way! -(NSRect)rectOfTickMarkAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    return NSZeroRect;
}

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`-[NSSlider setNumberOfTickMarks:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSlider_Class/Reference/Reference.html) method to set the number of tick marks to zero. This will hide them.

In Interface Builder you can just set this to zero in the inspector panel.

Comment: Yes, but then it won't stop at Integers values. I am using tick marks so the user can only stop at say 5 rather than 5.5. But if I remove the tick marks, then the slider can stop anywhere. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: @user: Just set up a `NSNumberFormatter` that only outputs integer values. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can override `[NSSliderCell drawTickMarks]` and do nothing in your implementation.

Make sure to set your subclass as the NSSlider's cell.

Comment: That used to work, but stopped working for us in 10.14. Overriding rectOfTickMarkAtIndex still works.